# disabling c++ output message for sql loader

Tags: c++, linux, g++, sql-loader

I have a C++ code in which I am using sql loader using `system()`. When SQL Loader executes while running the code, I got below mentioned messages which I want to disable:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Mar 14 14:11:25 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 20
Commit point reached - logical record count 40
Commit point reached - logical record count 60
Commit point reached - logical record count 80
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `silent=ALL` option to suppress these messages:

```
system("/orahomepath/bin/sqlldr silent=ALL ...")
```

See also [SQL*Loader Command-Line Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm#g1014550):

> As SQL*Loader executes, you also see feedback messages on the screen, for example:
>
> Commit point reached - logical record count 20
>
> You can suppress these messages by specifying SILENT with one or more values:
>
> - ...
> - ALL - Implements all of the suppression values: HEADER, FEEDBACK, ERRORS, DISCARDS, and PARTITIONS.

Depending on the sql*ldr implementation, you **might** still end up with one or the other output - if you need complete silence, see the answer from @Joachim below.

Comment: Just be aware that SILENT=ALL will also apply that filter to the log file, not just what you see on your terminal screen

Answer (score 4):

Remember that the `system` function uses the shell to execute the command. So you can use normal shell redirection:

```
system("/some/program > /dev/null");
```